# Spark JDBC write to Teradata - how to write parallel queries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I have a dataframe of around 20 million rows and 5 columns that I want to write to Teradata. Problem I am facing is its taking an absolute age to load as we can use one partition as the table will lock with multiple partitions. I have tried using the FASTLOAD parameter but it times out with a preparedStatement getNextException. Unfortunately I don't have access to the logs (the way our organisation is set up, we use an internal ETL tool that uses spark)

is anyone able to help?

code I am currently using is

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:teradata://<organisation_url>/Database=db,TYPE=FASTLOAD")
.option("dbtable", "tbl_name")
.option("user", "user")
.option("password","pword")
.option("driver","com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
.option("numPartitions",1)
.mode("overwrite").save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `FLATTEN=ON` connection parameter in the JDBC connection URL, to combine the chained exceptions together into a single exception:

```
.option("url", "jdbc:teradata://<organisation_url>/Database=db,TYPE=FASTLOAD,FLATTEN=ON")
```

Your inserted data may have a bad data value that the database is rejecting. Hopefully with `FLATTEN=ON` you will be able to see the problem.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I am using JDBC driver 17.00.00 so don't have flatten as an option, again something enforced by my organisation. I've decided to load into a few staging tables which has sped the process up

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses lazy evaluation, so you need to provide more details on from where you are reading data.
if you are using JDBC to read data then you can use numPartitions to trigger multiple threads to read data for example 100 threads, so in this case 100 threads will write data parallel to Teradata